# Evaluate $\int_{3}^{10} \left[ \log \left[x\right]\right]dx$

Tags: integration, algebra-precalculus, definite-integrals

Evaluate $$I=\int_{3}^{10} \left[ \log \left[x\right]\right]dx$$ where $[.]$ is Greatest integer function.

My try:

we have $$I=\sum_{r=3}^{9}\int_{r}^{r+1}\left[\log r\right]dx$$

but how can we split further?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Hint:* $1 \le \log r \le 2 $ for $r \in [3,9]$. The breakpoint is at $r=e^2$.

Comment: See [WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+floor(log(x))+for+x%3D3..9) for a plot.

Answer (score 2):

The integrand starts at $1$ and ends at $2$, increasing to the latter value at $x=8$. So $$I=\int_3^8 dx+\int_8^{10}2dx=5+4=9.$$

Comment: @RossMillikan Thanks for catching the copy-paste typo.